# Add Missing Hyphens on second line when hyphen only exists on first line with regex

Tags: regex

Need to ADD missing hyphen on second line when hyphen only exists on first line only:

```
24
00:03:01,848 --> 00:03:04,893
- How adorable.
[both laughing]

48
00:02:53,798 --> 00:02:54,758
[clears throat]

49
00:02:57,552 --> 00:02:59,971
- [clears throat] Phil.
What can I get you?

168
00:07:01,421 --> 00:07:03,048
Really?
- If that's possible, yeah.

169
00:07:03,089 --> 00:07:04,007
- Really?
- Mm-hmm.
```

Here's what I thought might work [no cigar]:

```
Find:       ^([- ])(?=.*\r?\n([A-Za-z\[]))
Replace:    - $1
```

The CORRECT end results would be as follows with both lines having hyphens:

```
24
00:03:01,848 --> 00:03:04,893
- How adorable.
- [both laughing]

48
00:02:53,798 --> 00:02:54,758
[clears throat]

49
00:02:57,552 --> 00:02:59,971
- [clears throat] Phil.
- What can I get you?
```

Thanks in Advance, Hank

Comment: More ideas: [Replace `^(-.*\n)(?![\s-])` to `$1- `](https://regex101.com/r/gE3MiO/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match a line that starts with a `-` followed by a line that *doesn't* start with `-`. Use a negative lookahead to implement the "doesn't start with" criteria.

Then you want to *add* a `-` to the end of whatever this matched.

Find: `^-.*$\r?\n(?!- )(?=.)`
Replace: `$0-`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tvgcsT/3)

Comment: sorry was having a brain fart, not use to how this message board works. Your solution works GREAT.. Thanks a Bunch

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/re0Cta/1)):

```
^(-\s+.*?)^([^-])
```

with flags MULTILINE and SINGLELINE. Substitution is string:

```
$1- $2
```

Comment: This one did not find?